# Wicket datatable footer

Tags: datatable, sum, wicket, footer

I want to add footer to a datatable. It will do some statistic work like "sum". Can anyone show me how to do this? It will be great if you show me some examples. Thanks!

Regards

Comment: in what program? need more data!

Comment: You mean the sum of the items currently on screen? Or a global sum of all the items?

Comment: in Java. and it is global sum of a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. In this example we will create page with table with invoices. One invoice in each row. At the bottom of the table will be toolbar in which will be shown the sum of all invoices.

**Invoice.java** (Object that represents one invoice)

```
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    private String description;
    private int sum;

    public Invoice() {}

    public Invoice(String description, int sum) {
        this.description = description;
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

**InvoiceDataProvider.java** (Data provider for the table)

```
public class InvoiceDataProvider implements IDataProvider {

    private List<Invoice> invoices;

    public InvoiceDataProvider(IModel<Double> sumModel) {
        invoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
        invoices.add(new Invoice("for rent", 550));
        invoices.add(new Invoice("for phone", 25));
        invoices.add(new Invoice("for insurance", 10));

        // reset sumModel
        sumModel.setObject(0.0);
        // count the sum of invoices
        for (Invoice invoice : invoices) {
            sumModel.setObject(sumModel.getObject() + invoice.getSum());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator(long first, long count) {
        return invoices.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public IModel model(final Object object) {
        return new AbstractReadOnlyModel<Invoice>() {
            @Override
            public Invoice getObject() {
                return (Invoice) object;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public long size() {
        return invoices.size();
    }
}
```

In the data provider we get data to be shown in the table (invoices list). Than we count sum of the invoices in the list and add the result to the model.

**InvoicesToolbar.java** (The toolbar for the table. Here the total sum of invoices will be shown)

```
public class InvoicesToolbar extends AbstractToolbar {

    private IModel<Double> sumModel;

    public InvoicesToolbar(DataTable table, IModel sumModel) {
        super(table);

        this.sumModel = sumModel;

        add(new Label("sumText", Model.of("total sum")));
        add(new Label("sumNumber", sumModel));
    }
}
```

We save sumModel and create two labels. The label 'sumText' will show text 'total sum' and label 'sumNumber' will show the value stored in the model (sumModel).

**InvoicesToolbar.html** (The toolbar is panel so the appropriate html file should be created)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <tr>
        <td><span wicket:id="sumText"></span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="sumNumber"></span></td>
    </tr>
</wicket:panel>
```

We create one table row with two cells (the table will have two columns) and add html elements with wicket id to render there some text.

**DataTablePage.java** (The web page with the table)

```
public class DataTablePage extends WebPage {

    public DataTablePage() {
        List<IColumn> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn>();
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(Model.of("description"), "description"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn(Model.of("sum"), "sum"));

        IModel<Double> sumModel = new Model<Double>(0.0);

        DataTable table = new DataTable("table", columns, new InvoiceDataProvider(sumModel), 10);
        table.addTopToolbar(new HeadersToolbar(table, null));
        table.addBottomToolbar(new InvoicesToolbar(table, sumModel));
        add(table);
    }
}
```

We create list of columns (PropertyColumn - value will be the property of the object). We create model (sumModel). In this model will be lately stored the total sum of the invoices. And we create table. To this table (to the top) we add header toolbar (headers for the columns) and (to the bottom) we add our InvoiceToolbar.

**DataTablePage.html** (Html markup for the web page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table wicket:id="table"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Above the wicket-core dependency we also need wicket-extensions dependency. The code was tested using wicket 6.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

When populating the data table, say for instance with a ListView, you should increment an Integer Model that will be used later in a Label.

```
     Model sumModel = new Model(0);
        listview = new ListView(...) {
            ... populate(ListItem item) {
                int N = // whatever value you need
                sumModel.setObject(sumModel.getObject() + N);
            }
        }
        add(listview);
        // ...
        Label sumFooter = new Label("footer", sumModel);
        add(sumFooter);
```

PS: I have not tested this.

**edit**
You should check CountLabel component aswell

(http://opensource.55minutes.com/apidocs/fiftyfive-wicket-all/4.0-SNAPSHOT/fiftyfive/wicket/basic/CountLabel.html)